# RESTful api for dynamic showform on top of spring mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, rest

I want to build a typical mvc app for CRUD of simple items, the api s should be RESTful. The catch here is, that i have a large pallete of items that needs to be initialized. On the server side those items are defined as java beans and the corresponding create form for the item is dynamically created from the field information(data type, validation constraints etc) harvested from the bean.
  I am new to REST and just read up about how the urls should be nouns defining the resource and action specified by HTTP verb. In that perspective how to model something like 
`.../client/showForm?type=xyz` from non RESTful way to RESTful one ?? My intention here is to tell the server to dynamically construct and send back a CREATE form for client of type xyz. The obvious problem with url i mentioned above is that it specifies action in the url which, from what i have read, makes it non RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

When I think of REST, I think of resources. I think of data. In other words, I don't think of REST as being something that I would typically use to retrieve a form, which is a user interface component.

REST is an architectural style that is used to identify a resource on a server using a uniform resource identifier, or URI. Additionally, actions performed on those resources identified by the URI are determined based on the specific HTTP Method used in the request:  GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

Thus, let's say you have a Client object. That client object might have the following properties:

- Name
- Location
- AccountNumber

If I wanted to retrieve the data for a single client, I might use the following URI:

```
GET /client/xyz/   # xyx is the accountnumber used to identify the client.
```

I would use a GET method, since REST describes GET as being the method to use when retrieving data from the server.

The data could theoretically be returned in HTML, since REST is not a standard but more like a series of flexible guidelines; however, to really decouple my data from my user interface, I would choose to use something platform independent like JSON or XML to represent the data.

Next, when adding a client to the collection on the server, I would use the /client/ URI pattern, but I would use the HTTP Method POST, which is used when adding a resource to a collection on the server.

```
# Pass the data as JSON to the server and tell the server to add the client to the 
 # collection
POST /client/    {"accountnumber":"abc" , "Name" : "Jones" , "Location" : "Florida"}
```

If I were to modify an existing record on the server or replace it, I would most likely use the HTTP Method PUT, since REST guidelines say that PUT should be used if repeating the same operation repeatedly would not change the state of the server.

```
# Replace the client abc with a new resource
PUT /client/abc/  {"accountnumber":"abc" , "Name" : "Bob Jones" , "Location" : "Florida"}
```

The general idea behind REST is that it is used to identify a resource and then take action on that resource based on what HTTP Method is used.

If you insist on coupling your data with your view, one way accomplish this and retrieve the actual form, with the client data, could be to represent the form as a resource itself:

```
GET /client/abc/htmlform/
```

This URL would of course return your client data for client abc, but in an HTML form that would be rendered by the browser.

While my style of coding utilizes data transports such as JSON or XML to abstract and separate my data from my view, you could very well transport that data as HTML. However, the advantage of using JSON or XML is that your RESTful API becomes platform independent. If you ever expand your API to where other developers wish to consume it, they can do so, regardless of what specific platform or programming language they are using. In other words, the API could be used my PHP, Java, C#, Python, Ruby, or Perl developers.

In other words, any language or platform that can make HTTP requests and can send GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests can be used to extend or build upon your API. This is the true advantage of REST.

For more information on setting up your controllers to use REST with Spring MVC, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561268/552792). Additionally, check out the [Spring MVC Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for more information.

Also, if you haven't checked out the [Wikipedia article on REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), I strongly encourage you to do so. Finally, another good, classic read on REST is [How I Explained REST To My Wife](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife). Enjoy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that answer, when we create a resource using a REST api the implicit understanding is that the user knows details about the resource i.e the fields for which it should send data. But what if , the user has to discover that information prior to be able to create the resource. Would you model a ResourceRepository as a separate REST resource querying which the user can discover about the resource that he intends to create ?

Comment: while exploring your idea around `GET /client/abc/htmlform/` and listening to this [ian robinson talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Getting-Things-Done-with-REST) i was thinking if what i want fits into this HATEOAS thing, i mean i dont want the html form per se but the field info ,data for which needs to be supplied for a successfull create of 'abc'(from example above), what gets hairy though is this whole thing of interdependent fields and stuff. From my little reading into HATEOAS thing looks like one shud be able to do such things but i dont know how

Comment: @redzedi - I'm not familiar with HATEOAS, but I'll check out your links tomorrow.